# Getting "undefined reference to `vtable`" error for parameterized constructor

Tags: c++, linker-errors, undefined-reference, vtable, pure-virtual

I have this error coming up:

> undefined reference to `vtable`

I'm unable to figure out the root cause of it.

I did try to search in Google, but still unable to figure out the reason.

Here is the code:

**IState.hpp** -> Complete state interface class

```
class IState {

    public:

        IState() = delete;

        IState(ICallbacks &callbacks)
        : m_callbacks(callbacks) {
        }

        virtual ~IState() = default;

        IState(IState &state)
        :m_callbacks(state.m_callbacks) {
        };

        IState& operator=(IState &state) {
            this->m_callbacks = state.m_callbacks;
            return *this;
        };

        IState(IState &&state) = delete;
        IState& operator=(IState &&state) = delete;

        bool operator== (const IState &state) {
            return (this->state_id == state.state_id);
        }

        virtual const IError& stateEntry(ISubject &Subject) = 0;
        virtual const IError& stateExit(ISubject &Subject) = 0;
    
    private:
        std::string state_id = std::string("");
        ICallbacks& m_callbacks;
};
```

**CState.hpp** -> Partial implementation of interface class

```
class CState : public IState {

    public:

        CState() = delete;

        CState(ICallbacks &callbacks)
        : IState(callbacks),
          m_ccallbacks(static_cast<CCallbacks&>(callbacks)) {
        }

        virtual ~CState() {
            
        };

        CState(CState &state)
        :IState(state),
         m_ccallbacks(static_cast<CCallbacks&>(state.m_ccallbacks))  {

        }

        CState& operator=(CState &state) {
            this->m_ccallbacks = static_cast<CCallbacks&>(state.m_ccallbacks);
            return *this;
        }

        CState(CState &&state) = delete;
        CState& operator=(CState &&state) = delete;

        const IError& stateEntry(ISubject &Subject) override {
            CSubject &cSubject = static_cast<CSubject&>(Subject);
            return StateEntry(cSubject);
        };
        const IError& stateExit(ISubject &Subject) override {
            CSubject &cSubject = static_cast<CSubject&>(Subject);
            return StateExit(cSubject);
        }

        virtual const IError& StateEntry(CSubject &Subject) = 0;
        virtual const IError& StateExit(CSubject &Subject) = 0;
    
    private:
        CCallbacks& m_ccallbacks;
};
```

**ActiveState.hpp** -> Complete implementation of `CState.hpp`

```
class ActiveState : public CState {

    public:

        ActiveState() = delete;

        ActiveState(ICallbacks &callbacks)
        : CState(callbacks) {

        }

        ActiveState(ActiveState &state)
        : CState(state) {
        }

        ActiveState& operator=(ActiveState &state) = default;

        virtual ~ActiveState() {

        }

        const IError& StateEntry(CSubject &Subject) override {
            return NO_ERROR;
        };
        const IError& StateExit(CSubject &Subject) override {
            return NO_ERROR;
        };
};
```

Now, whenever I create an `ActiveState` object using a base class pointer, it goes through compilation, but fails in linking with this error:

```
In function `ActiveState::ActiveState(ICallbacks&)':
File.cpp:(.text.11ActiveStateC2ERNS2_15ICallbacksE[_ZN611ActiveStateC5ERNS2_15ICallbacksE]+0x26): undefined reference to `vtable for ActiveState'
```

Please let me know where I am going wrong, and how to solve this problem.

Comment: Try `virtual ~ActiveState()=default;` or put the implementation in the .cpp file. If that does not work, create a [mcve], this is a linker error yet I see no translation units in your question, headers are almost irrelevant to this.

Comment: gcc seems to want to put the vtable in the object file where the first virtual function is implemented. Don't know what happens when there is no object file. Perhaps this?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with the shown code. Please form a [mre].

Comment: Some compilers use the strategy of generating the virtual function table into the object file by the source file translation unit that implements the first non-inline virtual function.

Comment: @Quimby: I tried putting in minimal reproducible code. But its working in that case by virtual ~ActiveState()=default;, but not in the actual case. Not sure how to put forward as I cannot share the complete code and whatever I have shared earlier seems to have problem.

Comment: @BoP Is it something to do with inheritance.
I mean CState inherited from IState and ActiveState from CState. stateEntry and stateExit are only overridden in CState, which has its own set of virtual function StateEntry and StateExit that has been overridden by ActiveState. I am unable to figure out.

Comment: On a side note: `IState`'s copy constructor/`operator=` should take the `IState` by `const` reference, or just be `default`ed. Same with `CState` and `ActiveState`. Also `CState(ICallbacks&)` and `ActiveState(ICallbacks&)` should be changed to take `CCallbacks&` instead, since that is what they actually expect. Also, the type-cast in `CState(CState&)` is unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry guys,
It was a problem with CMakeLists.txt.
The CMakeLists.txt was missing ActiveState.cpp in GLOB.
Hence this error.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: That just happens sometimes :D